# How to not crop ImageView inside a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, crop, android-image

## Hi, I'm trying to make something like this

[image: what i want]

## And this is what I get

[image]

### This is the xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/category_item_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/planetImage"
                android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/earth_transparent"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/planetName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Mars"
                android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_extrabold"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/planetViews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_extrabold"
                android:text="155 views"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The image is cropped and I can't figure out how to predict that.
I don't care about colour difference right now, I just want to set something, so it doesn't crop the image.

Comment: A layout only shows views that are inside of its bounds. To achieve what you want, the ImageView needs to be outside of the inner layout. I suggest looking at [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) and using it for your entire view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put imageview outside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/category_item_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/planetName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_extrabold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Mars"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/planetViews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_extrabold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="155 views" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/planetImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/earth_transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```